# Change value of XML attribute with sed

Tags: xml, bash, sed

I need to add a build number to the `version` attribute value of my xml file:

```
<widget id="com.test.enterprise.operationsnew" version="2.4.2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

In my bash script I've tried:

```
BUILD_NUMBER=1
VERSION="$(xmllint \
  -xpath 'string(//*[local-name()="widget"]/@version)' config.xml | \
  cut -f1-3 -d.)"
CFBundleVersion="${VERSION}.${BUILD_NUMBER}"

sed -i '' \
  -e 's#version="[0-9].[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]"#version="${CFBundleVersion}"#g' \
  config.xml
```

The `CFBundleVersion` variable does get inserted, but not resolved:

```
<widget id="com.test.enterprise.operationsnew" version="${CFBundleVersion}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

How can I do this properly with sed?

Comment: Variables are not expanded in single quotes by the shell. Sed has no notion of variables.

Comment: I don't know how to use, but I think you should use something like `xmlstarlet` instead of using `sed`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 sed -e 's#version="[0-9].[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]"#version="'${CFBundleVersion}'"#g' config.xml
```

Add single quotes around the variable to expand it.